# How to use the NoSuchElementException in Iterator.next()?

Tags: java, design-patterns, interface, iterator

I wonder why the Iterator.next() throws a NoSuchElementException. Usually if you use an iterator you will do something like:

```
for(MyClass o: myFancyObject) {
    o.doSomething();
}
```

which will be compiled as

```
Iterator it = myFancyObject.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    MyClass o = (MyClass)(iterator.next());
    o.doSomething();
}
```

But why is the next() method  to throw a NoSuchElementException?

So let us call the hasNext() method in the next() method like below:

```
public MyClass next() {
    if (! hasNext())
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    return mySecretDataModel.getElement(counter++);
}
```

But then I detect following problem: The hasNext() method will be called twice in each iteration. First it is called from the method which uses the iterator and then a second time by the next() method. This costs unnecessary computing time. Is this intention or just a design oversight by the authors of the Iterator interface?

Comment: The question is indeed kind of unclear. "But then I detect following problem: The hasNext() method will be called twice in each iteration. First it is called from the method which uses the iterator and then a second time by the next() method" This is usually considered a bad practice, I think. It's called a side effect. It's bad exactly due to the problem you're noticing.

Comment: The JavaDoc of Iterator<E> says:
  "Throws:
     NoSuchElementException - if the iteration has no more elements"

So, am I required to follow this contract or is it enough only to implement hasNext()?

Comment: I think it's fine, as long as the method is [idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotent).

Comment: @MariusSpix: hasNext() is probably extremely fast, and breaking the contract of Iterator to gain a few nanoseconds every hour is a bad idea. Don't pre-optimize: it's the root of all evil. And trust the JIT to compile your frequently used code to fast native code.

Answer (score 1):

The `iterator` might throw NoSuchElementException for a few reasons, but the most obvious is the caller not invoking `hasNext()` or ignoring the result.

Answer (score 0):

You would write it like this

```
public MyClass next() {
    if (counter >= mySecretDataModel.getSize())
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    return mySecretDataModel.getElement(counter++);
}
```

Comment: But "if (counter >= mySecretDataModel.size())" is also checked in hasNext() ... So there is still a double check.

Comment: @MariusSpix In that case, it doesn't check anything which can't be performed twice and the performance cost is notional as the branch prediction will skip over the common case that the condition is false.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think one needs to call `hasNext()`, a better way is to:

```
public MyClass next() {
    if (counter >= mySecretDataModel.size())
        throw new NoSuchElementException();

    return mySecretDataModel.getElement(counter++);
}
```

Another option is that you store your iterator state which is a pair of `MyObject nextElement` and `boolean hasNext` in a field being computed during `hasNext()`, so there is no twice calling.

Answer (score 0):

You're absolutely right in both statements. The first one (despite all other answers here) is that we should call `hasNext()` from `next()`, in order to avoid code duplication. The second one is that calling `hasNext()` twice is an unnecessary operation, computing cost wise.

We are doing this call to `hasNext()` from `next()` because of being [**defensive**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming). We can skip this operation and let `next()` assume that `hasNext()` was already called and our client knows what he is doing. But this may lead to unexpected and unpredictable exceptions, like `NullPointerException`, for example.

So, the answer here is - [defensive programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming) is a good thing, even though it costs something.